# Cross tabulation plot with numbers in R

Tags: r

I would like to add the frequency numbers of each combination on a cross-tabulation plot.

For example, with the `mtcars` example:

```
data("mtcars")
table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)
```

We have the number of each combination between `$vs` and `$am` columns. If I directly plot this, I get 4 rectanges which size vary based on the frequency numbers:

```
plot(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), main = "Cross tabulation plot",
     xlab = "Engine (vs)", ylab = "Transmission (am)")
```

[image]

Would it be possible to print these frequency numbers within the corresponding rectangle in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way you can show a number in each square.
Basically the idea is to calculate the position of the numbers so that they will fit the center of the square.

```
tbl <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)
prpX <- prop.table(table(mtcars$vs))
prpY <- prop.table(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), margin = 1)

plot(tbl, main = "Cross tabulation plot",
     xlab = "Engine (vs)", ylab = "Transmission (am)")
text(prpX/2 * c(1,-1) + 0:1,
     prpY/2 * c(-1,-1,1,1) + c(1,1,0,0),
     tbl)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, and if we want the raw numbers instead of percentages? You just the labels, I guess: `text(prpX/2 * c(1, -1) + 0:1, prpY/2 * c(-1, -1, 1, 1) + c(1, 1, 0, 0), labels = table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)[1:4])`